# Не удается сравнить даты

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

Не удается сравниить даты при фильтрации выборки из БД.

Получаю данные :

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0, 0));

var callEventRequest = await this._userCallEventRepository.GetAsync(cancellationToken,
            x => (x.Type == Domain.Enums.CallType.Income 
            || x.Type == Domain.Enums.CallType.Outcome 
            || x.Type == Domain.Enums.CallType.Redirected) && x.CallInitialTime > dt)
```

`x.CallInitialTime` это свойство, содержащее дату из БД PgSql.
Тип свойства `DateTime`.

В pgAdmin данные имеют следующий вид
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как бы я ни сравнивал, на выходе я получаю null.
Если убрать из фильтрации `x.CallInitialTime > dt`, то получаю все записи из БД.
А нужны записи за последние 3 дня.

Что я делаю не так?
Вроде в шарпе даты можно сравнивать как обычные числа без лишних танцев с бубном.

UPD.
Эти данный приходят с БД, если убрать из условия дату
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

GetAsync. В примере запроса выше я опустил параметры сортировки и include, чтобы не фонить не нужной информацией. Они тут никак не влияют

```
async Task<Result<IEnumerable<T>>> IReadonlyRepository<T>.GetAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>>? filter,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>>? sort,
        string? include)
    {
        try
        {
            var res = await Entities
                .AddFilter(filter)
                .AddIncludes(include)
                .AddSort(sort)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
            return Result.Ok((IEnumerable<T>)res);
        }
```

Сделал я вот так:

```
x.CallInitialTime.DayOfYear > dt.DayOfYear
```

И это сработало. Только вот в новогоднюю ночь такой код превратится в тыкву :
При этом если использовать `DateTime.Ticks`, который должен вернуть long, то опять же ничего не работает. WTF

Comment: у вас все даты здесь одинаковые. А даты можно сравнивать, да

Comment: поставь точку дебага на строчке сравнения и посмотри что в этих двух переменных. а лучше приложи код

Comment: Внутри репозитория что используется: EF, EF Core, что-то ещё? / Покажите код метода `GetAsync`.

Comment: Примечание: согласно гайдлайнам, `CancellationToken` должен быть последним параметром метода. / Метка asp.net-core лишняя, т. к. вопрос не связан с этим веб-фреймворком. Аналогично, метка pgadmin4. Разве что в самом вопросе можно указать, что скриншот сделан в этом инструменте.

Comment: @aepot Да , все верно. Это просто моковые данные. Сам факт, что не получается сравнить даты и получить выборку за последний 3 дня

Comment: @RuslanGorbunov я дополнил пост скриншотом полями, полученными из БД

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov прикрепил код GetAsync. Используется EF Core.

Comment: Так, припоминаю, что я когда-то участвовал в разборе этих методов репозитория. Один ответ нашёл, второго не вижу - очевидно, вопрос был удалён. А хотелось бы в него заглянуть, чтобы повторно не ломать голову. / Меня интересует, как реализован вызов `Where` в самом EF. То есть метод `AddFilter`.

Comment: Похоже, тут дело в таймзоне/оффсете. А что, если с показанными данными отнять четыре дня от текущей даты, а не три? / Глянул я данные по Постгресу - `timestamp` должен маппиться на `DateTimeOffset`. И вообще, практически всегда нужно использовать `DateTimeOffset` для указания конкретных дат во времени.

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть сгенерированный SQL-запрос. Для этого или логирование в DbContext нужно включить, либо вызвать `ToQueryString`.

Comment: Ну и раз уж начал писать. В DbContext могут быть добавлены перехватчики (Interceptors). Да и много чего ещё может вмешиваться в процесс работы с БД. Поэтому либо код контекста нужен (честно - не хочу его видеть...), либо (что лучше) - сгенерированный SQL.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dt = DateTime.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
```

или

```
var dt = DateTime.Now.Date - TimeSpan.FromDays(3);
```

если нужно с начала суток.

Хотя 'DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0, 0))' даёт то же самый результат. Дело не в дате.

Судя по картинке, нужно использовать DateTimeOffset

Comment: Offset тоже не спас ситуациб )
Засада еще что по точке останова как фильтрация происходит. Что с чем сранивается.
Не понятно на чет отшибает проверка. 
Хотя без условия визуально из БД достается обычная дата. По логике должны сравниваться

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решился просто
Вместо `var dt = DateTime.Now.Subtract(new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0, 0));`

нужно было прописать
`var dt = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new TimeSpan(3, 0, 0, 0));`